# Nested sortable AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, nested-sortable

I want to create nested sortable lists using AngularJS. I'm not sure that there is existing solution out there. I tried using https://github.com/mostr/angular-ui-multi-sortable, and it works fine, but unfortunately, seems like it doesn't accept nested lists.

What I actually need is to have like multiple baskets, where I can reorder these baskets, and also drag/drop products from baskets (from one basket to another).

Does anyone have idea/solution how to work with this?

Thanks!

Comment: plz provide a jsfiddle or plunker, it would help us a lot in helping you :)

Comment: ok, I managed to do this, I used two different directives, one for sorting baskets, and the other one for drag&drop items between baskets. I used ui-sortable, and multi-sortable, in case someone needed.

Comment: Post your solution and accept if you found a solution.  That way people like me who search for unanswered angular questions to answer won't come by here anymore :)

Comment: Please post your solution! http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Please post the answer!! I need that too!

Comment: I had to change the way it functions, so I don't have exact code, but I will provide thing that I did. It's not really nested (in terms that you can add one item as a child of other).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just written an angularjs ui component for this.

Try this one:
https://github.com/JimLiu/Angular-NestedSortable

Comment: Hey, Jim, this looks pretty good! Finally we went with another approach and we didn't need nested component, but in case someone else needs it, I hope yours will help. Regarding ours directive, it will be on github in next few days, and I'll publish it here (however, it's not nested).

Comment: Any chance this could be made to allow for selecting multiple elements (at once) to drag and drop?